# Can I have different colored left and top borders in CSS?

Tags: css, border

I would like to have a border that is 4px thick pink on the left and 1px grey elsewhere:

```css
border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
border-left: 4px solid #F24495;
```

The issue is the join is diagonal so I get a horrible overlay. I tried:

```css
.item:before{ 
  border-left: 4px solid #F24495;
}
```

But no luck.

### jsFiddle Example

- [jsFiddle example highlighting diagonal connection](http://jsfiddle.net/ex6ZR/)

### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a straight joint, and how that differs from your screenshot.

Comment: What you seem to be asking for (a vertically or horizontally aligned join between top border and left border) isn't possible with CSS alone as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Perhaps use vector graphics (I don't know).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

`.item::before` was the right approach, but it needs a bit of work past a single `border-left` property. You'll need to make the pseudo element visible (`display: block; content: "";`), position the pseudo element on the left side of `.item`, and stretch it to line up with the top and bottom borders properly.

While this can be done manually, I highly recommend using [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) (or [variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature) in your [preprocessor](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-2)) since it makes updating the widths of borders less error-prone and painful.

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.2em 0.3em;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  color: #454545;

  /* Set border widths with variables */
  --top-border-width: 4px;
  --bottom-border-width: var(--top-border-width);
  --left-border-width: 16px;
  --right-border-width: var(--top-border-width);

  /* Set border styles for each side */
  border-top: var(--top-border-width) solid #e4e4e4;
  border-bottom: var(--bottom-border-width) solid #e4e4e4;
  border-right: var(--right-border-width) solid #e4e4e4;

  /* Remove the left border and add blank space where the border should be placed */
  border-left: 0;
  margin-left: var(--left-border-width);

  /* Contain the ::before */
  position: relative;
}

.item::before {
  /* Give the pseudo element substance */
  display: block;
  content: "";

  /* Add a left border with a straight edge */
  border-left: var(--left-border-width) solid #f84995;

  /* Position pseudo element's border where the normal border would have been placed */
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(0px - var(--top-border-width));
  bottom: calc(0px - var(--bottom-border-width));
  left: calc(0px - var(--left-border-width));
}
```

```html
<h1 class="item">Gen.2</h1>
```

Comment: Modified so that the top and bottom "contain" the left border, and also demonstrates treatment of right border in similar situation: http://jsfiddle.net/ex6ZR/11/

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to use the `:before` pseudo selector you need to set some content as well. See for example [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NeaSh/1/) with the following sample code:

```
<div>Container</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    border: 10px solid black;
    border-left-width: 0;
}
div::before {
    border: 10px solid orange;
    border-right-width: 0;
    content: '';
}
```

Displays as:

[image: Screenshot from working code]

**Edit**
Hmm, although this should strictly answer the question, while trying to adapt my solution into the question's fiddle I find this doesn't play very well with paddings. Open to suggestions/edits/other answers that can handle that bit :(...

Comment: I think this is going to help with a bit of work.  The issue I have is the :before then ignores the padding. 

[example pic](http://i.imgur.com/EAvEO.png)

Comment: In fact I can fix this by adding the padding to the :before

Comment: @KevinMann, keep in mind this code breaks once multiple lines (either with `<br>` or simply wrapping) are introduced ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/NeaSh/2/)). However, my answer does not ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/ex6ZR/5/)).

Comment: In the end I added padding-right: 5px; to the :before and the same to the item and it worked perfectly see [here](http://i.imgur.com/LKhHF.png)

Answer (score 7):

this should work but requires extra markup:

```
.outer {
    border: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    border-left: 0;
}

.inner {
    border-left: 4px solid #F24495;
}
```

and

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks a little bit edgy with roundes corners though, make sure to set radius to 0 for the affected corners

Comment: A problem with this approach is that the top border will still overlap with the left border. Have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Felixito/6s4vr7yg/1/)

Comment: You can have look at my answer below to see how both issues can be fixed with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

By default CSS uses [miter joints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miter_joint) (45° angles) for all borders joints. Hence, to achieve square joints (90° angles) for any border, you can either use (1) inner [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow), (2) [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) or (3) [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) and multiple [linear-gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient).

Let's assume you have the following element that you want to style:

```html
<div></div>
```

#### Option 1: square joints using `box-shadow`

```css
div {
  /* downside of using box-shadow, you need to add the   */
  /* inner border size to the padding on top of any      */
  /* additional padding you might want                   */
  padding: 20px;
  /* by changing the order of your box-shadows, you      */
  /* can modify which borders overlap each other         */
  box-shadow:
    /* left "inner border" */
    inset 20px 0 0 0 red,
    /* right "inner border" */
    inset -20px 0 0 0 grey,
    /* top "inner border" */
    inset 0 20px 0 0 grey,
    /* bottom "inner border" */
    inset 0 -20px 0 0 grey;
}
```

- [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Lgu6zp2/)
- [Browser support for `box-shadow`](https://caniuse.com/#search=box-shadow)

#### Option 2: square joints `pseudo-elements`

```css
div {
  border: 20px solid grey;
}

div::before {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  content: "";
  width: 20px;
  /* we need to add the height of the top and bottom    */
  /* border to the pseudo-elements' height as the       */
  /* inset border is not included in the height of the  */
  /* div even when "box-sizing: border-box" is set.     */
  height: calc(100% + 20px + 20px);
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
}
```

- [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wfzxuqoj/)
- [Browser support for `pseudo-elements`](https://caniuse.com/#search=pseudo-elements)

#### Option 3: square joints using `background-image` and multiple `linear-gradients`

```css
div {
  /* downside of using multiple linear-gradients, you   */
  /* need to add the inner border size to the padding   */
  /* on top of any additional padding you might want    */
  padding: calc(20px + 10px);
  background-image: 
    /* left "inner border" */
    linear-gradient(to right, red 20px, transparent 20px),
    /* right "inner border" */
    linear-gradient(to left, grey 20px, transparent 20px),
    /* top "inner border" */
    linear-gradient(grey 20px, transparent 20px),
    /* bottom "inner border" */
    linear-gradient(to top, grey 20px, transparent 20px);
}
```

- [View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vqfx0sk9/)
- [Browser support for `background-images()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=background-image)
- [Browser support for `linear-gradient()`](https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient)

Answer (score 0):

A combination of wrapping two elements and using the [border-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width)-property worked quite well for me. Note that when you are using border-radius as well you will have to unset the affected sides. I included this in my example since border-radius is quite common to be used with borders.

### JSFiddle

[Click here](https://jsfiddle.net/Felixito/6s4vr7yg/8/)

### Code

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.outer {
  margin: 10px;
  border-left: solid lightblue;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border-width: 0 0 0 8px;
}

.inner {
  border: 7px solid grey;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-left: 0;
  padding: 16px;
}
```

### Output

[image]