# CSS border collapse different sizes in a div

Tags: html, css, border

Please take a look here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ztu267zp/1/

```
border:3px solid grey;
border-bottom: 8px solid red;
```

At the bottom corners you can see, that both the grey and the red borders intersect diagonally.

Can I cut the grey border to end at the bottom of the DIV and the red border having 100% width over the full distance?

Thank you very much,

Doing it right now with box-shadows, but also here, there is no clean edge in Chrome and FF:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pikLU.jpg

Thanks
matt

Comment: That's the way the borders render ... you can't change that. Instead you can use a pseudo-element to create the red rectangle

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing the Bevel Effect on the Corner of Borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684215/removing-the-bevel-effect-on-the-corner-of-borders)

Comment: Great, yes, duplicate. Did not find this one.

Comment: @hias have you been able to solve your problem with the solutions as stated in the possible duplicate?

Comment: Thanks bastiaan, yes would have worked out as well. Did use the code from panther in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about st. like that, using pseudoelement `after`?

```
#bord{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border:3px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 0;
    /*border-bottom: 8px solid red;*/
    position: relative;
}

#bord:after {
    display: block; 
    background: red; 
    height: 8px; 
    width: 100%; 
    content: ''; 
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: -8px; 
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 -3px;
    padding: 0 3px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ztu267zp/4/

Comment: Thanks, but how do you get the red border to full width.

Comment: Had still a problem with IE11 which did not want to make sharp edges. Seem that is was a problem due to compatibility modes of IE.

Answer (score 2):

its not possible but you can use something like this

```
<div id="bord">
<div class="line-cover">
</div>
```

css

```
#bord{
height:200px;
width:200px;
border:3px solid grey;
border-bottom: 8px solid white;
}
.line-cover{
position: relative;
border-bottom: 8px solid red;
width: 100%;
top: 200px;
padding: 0 3px;
left: -3px;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/5ngtLqd1/)

Comment: I think it´s possible without additional element, see my post above :-) And the better was is to position absolutely to the bottom of the element (when you change or don´t know height).

Comment: lol this was the question "Can I cut the grey border to end at the bottom of the DIV and the red border having 100%" now tell me do you cut borders?