# Applying multiple solid borders (without bevelled corners) using CSS and one class per border-side

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a grid with solid corners not triangle where they meet.  i.e. I want it to look like the one on the right, not the left
[image: ![left wrong, right is right]

I also want to be able to specify each border as a separate class,  because I'm generating this dynamically. Currently looks like this:

```
 .left{
        border-style: solid;
        border-left-color:#AAAAFF;
    }
    .right{
        border-style: solid;
        border-right-color:#AAAAFF;
    }
    .up{
        border-style: solid;
        border-top-color:#AAAAFF;
    }
    .down{
        border-style: solid;
        border-bottom-color:#AAAAFF;
    }

          
                <div class="cell left down up">
                </div>
            
                <div class="cell up right">
                </div>
            
                <div class="cell left up">
                </div>
           ....
```

The two options I've found online are to use drop-shadow [Removing the Bevel Effect on the Corner of Borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684215/removing-the-bevel-effect-on-the-corner-of-borders) or linear gradients.

I don't think I can do this with drop-shadow,  because you can't define individual 'sides'  and using gradient doesn't seem to work, you can define multiple gradients for one class, but with separate classes only the last one takes effect, even if they're transparent.

i.e.

```
.left{
        background: rgb(2,0,36);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%);
    }
    .right{
        background: rgb(2,0,36);
        background: linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%);
    }
    .up{
        background: rgb(2,0,36);
        background: linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%);
    }
    .down{
        background: rgb(2,0,36);
        background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%);
    }
```

gives this: (http://jsfiddle.net/n9skpe6h/1/ for worked example)

[image: Not what I want either]

Comment: "I don't want it to look like the one on the right, not the left" - which one do you want it to look like? As it stands we don't know as both are ruled out in your statement.

Comment: @AHaworth ironically I changed the image to make it clearer... didn't update the text!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS variables to set the color for the various sides.

Here is a simplified example. Each cell element has a background image made out of four linear gradients. The color of the 'border' is set to transparent unless the relevant class is added when it is set to white.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  }
.cell {
  --top: transparent;
  --bottom: transparent;
  --left: transparent;
  --right: transparent;
  width: 10vmin;
  height: 10vmin;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--top) 0 2px, transparent 2px 100%),
  linear-gradient(to top, var(--bottom) 0 2px, transparent 2px 100%),
  linear-gradient(to right, var(--left) 0 2px, transparent 2px 100%),
  linear-gradient(to left, var(--right) 0 2px, transparent 2px 100%);
}
.top {
  --top: white;
}
.bottom {
  --bottom: white;
}
.left {
  --left: white;
}
.right {
  --right: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="cell left right"></div>
<div class="cell left right top"></div>
<div class="cell right bottom"></div>
<div class="cell right"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: That works well, thanks.  To avoid a 'cut-out' corner on adjacent cells I had to use a negative margin (of half the border size.)  Then it works perfectly! https://jeffsergeant.pythonanywhere.com/