# Border-bottom overrides border-left?

Tags: html, css, border

Border bottom overrides on `border-left` so it looks like crooked at border-left bottom side. Any answer why `border-bottom` get preference and overrides on left?

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li class="selected">list 1</li>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 1</li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style:none
}
li {
    width:300px;
    padding:10px;
    height:50px;
    background:#ddd;
    border-bottom:1px solid #333;
}
li.selected {
    border-left:4px solid #f00;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/8VC2c/1/

Comment: `looks like crooked`? I don't see any issue on Chrome 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`borders` in `css` are diagonally intersect each other so you can not achieve that only by using `borders`, Please check this quastion for this...[Can I have different colored left and top borders in CSS with straight join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052202/can-i-have-different-colored-left-and-top-borders-in-css-with-straight-join)

Comment: Thanks.. achieved what i want with this way!

Answer (score 3):

Consider using an alternative way to achieve this effect by using `before` pseudo element :

```
li.selected {
    background:rgb(246, 246, 246);
    position: relative;
}

.selected:before {
  content: "";
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #f00;
}
```

An example : http://jsfiddle.net/8VC2c/2/

Comment: Thanks.. achieved what i want with this way!

Answer (score 0):

the rule is not overriden, your problem is that an 1px border with the same color as background is not visualized!

Change, for example, by `border-bottom:4px solid #66E710;`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8VC2c/3/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks yeah, so used an alternative way css `:before`