# Different borders on each side of a TextField

Tags: css, javafx, textfield, scenebuilder

How can I change a textfields borders color in a way that two vertical borders have a same color and two horizontal borders have a same color using CSS?

Is there any way to make four border lines have four different color?

Thanks

Comment: You can try it like this and adapt it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052202/can-i-have-different-colored-left-and-top-borders-in-css-with-straight-join

Comment: @NDY there is no `-fx-border-left` or ... in javafx css style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify 4 values in `-fx-border-color`, and they will be the colors of the top, right, bottom and left border, respectively.

```
-fx-border-color: red green blue yellow;
```

See `-fx-border-color` in [JavaFX CSS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region).